# Sybase: get list of stored procedures using a particular table

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase

I have 500 stored procedures in a Sybase database. Using SQL, can I get list of all stored procedures that are using a particular table say `tbl_books`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
Select distinct sysobjects.name
, case 
 when sysobjects.type = 'TR' then 'TRIGGER' 
 when sysobjects.type = 'P' then 'PROCEDURE' 
 when sysobjects.type = 'V' then 'VIEW' 
 else 'UNKNOWN' end type
from sysobjects inner join syscomments
on sysobjects.id = syscomments.id
where syscomments.text like '%tbl_books%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Initially I'd try `sp_depends`.

```
Syntax: sp_depends objname[, column_name]
```

For `objname` you can supply any object name, for example a table, view or sproc.

Comment: The question is other way round. He needs a functionality reverse to that of `sp_depends`.

Comment: @mtk. From the help: "Displays information about database object dependencies—the view(s), trigger(s), and procedure(s)—in the database that depend on a specified table or view" http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sprocs/html/sprocs/sprocs68.htm

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Need to read the documentation completely :)

Answer (score 2):

Using syscomments like for this will stop working if there is another tablename say
tbl_books_new. A better way would be to use sysdepends

```
select so1.name from
sysobjects so1, sysobjects so2, sysdepends sd
where so1.id = sd.id
and   so2.id = sd.depid
and   so2.name = 'tbl_books'
and   so1.type = 'P'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something along the lines of:

```
select proc_name from sysprocedures where proc_defn like "%tbl_books%"
```

Comment: sorry, i do not see coulmns proc_name and proc_defn in table sysprocedures;;

  
select top 5 * from sysprocedures
  
type id sequence status number version 
  ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- 
2 3031 0 1026 0 12500 
2 3031 1 1026 0 12500 
2 3031 2 1026 0 12500 
2 3031 3 1026 0 12500 
2 3031 4 1026 0 12500

Answer (score 0):

Please remember, that text column in syscomments is varchar(255), so one big procedure can consist of many lines in syscomments, thus, the above selects will not find the procedure name if the table name, you are searching for, has been split into 2 text rows in syscomments.

I suggest the following select, which will handle the above case:

```
declare @text varchar(100)
select @text        = "%tbl_books%"

select distinct o.name object
from sysobjects o,
    syscomments c
where o.id=c.id
and o.type='P'
and (c.text like @text
or  exists(
    select 1 from syscomments c2 
        where c.id=c2.id 
        and c.colid+1=c2.colid 
        and right(c.text,100)+ substring(c2.text, 1, 100) like @text 
    )
)
order by 1
```

-- kudos for this go to the creator of [ASEisql](http://code.google.com/p/aseisql/)

Comment: Yep..whenever i want some DB qeuries i too trust ASEisql tool.its really awesome tool:)